# Unix command to ignore lines that begins with X

Tags: unix, sed

I'm currently using a compiler that constantly returns warnings, I don't want to see the warnings. I've noticed that all warnings begin with the string "Note :", so I figured it's possible to filter out these lines.

I compile with

```
jrc *.jr
```

Is there a unix command that alters the output it gives to not print out the lines that begin with "Note :"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
grep -v "^Note:"
```

Also, you may want to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
command 2>&1 | grep -v "^Note:"
```

Comment: The command: 
`jrc *.jr 2>&1 | grep -v "^Note: "`
works perfectly. Thanks!!!

Anyone know what 2>&1 does? I'm curious. :)

Comment: It redirects stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1). Piping a command with | will take stdout, not stderr, from the command and send it "through" another command. Programs choose whether to display output on stdout or stderr, typically you display "normal" output on stdout and warnings/errors on stderr.

Comment: @user621449: `2>&1` means: redirect the filedescriptor 2 to whatever filedescriptor 1 is pointing at. On Unix, 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr. So this redirects stderr to the same "stream" as stdout. That's needed to that the error messages are grepped as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use sed.

```
sed '/^Note:/d'
```